# How to manage Google Analytics certificate safely on Azure websites

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, google-analytics, asp.net-core

I read [this tutorial](http://www.daimto.com/googleanalytics-authentication-csharp/) on how to use Google Analytics with C#.

I'd like to use it in my ASP.NET5 application, and I want to do it right. I need to use Service Account authentication (my app will grab the statistics and preset reports generated by me to the users).

- I want to keep the certificate out of the code repository
- I don't want to have to remember about it every time I deploy
- Best option would be to configure it in Azure Portal (like a connection string) - but they don't accept files in configuration as far as I know

Google serves the certificate in 2 forms

- JSON file
- p12 file

I was thinking about extracting values from JSON certificate and putting them into configuration, but I have to instntiate `X509Certificate2` which only takes a path to P12 file, or some mysterious `byte[] rawData` in constructor.

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(pathToP12File, "myPassword", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential( new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail) {
                                                   Scopes = scopes}.FromCertificate(certificate));
```

Any ideas what to do?

Answer (score 0):

For a WebApp, go to the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com):

1. Browse to your WebApp >> Settings > > Custom domains and SSL >> Upload Certificate and complete the process to use your certificate.  Next...
2. Set Application Settings to use the certificate: Settings >> Application settings - and in the App Settings section, added Key: WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES, Value: * (note - this can also be the thumbprint, or a comma separated list of thumbprints
3. Use code similar to below to retrieve the certificate (note - in WebApps the Certificates are stored in `StoreLocation.CurrentUser`:

   ```
   var thumb = "your-certificate-thumbprint";
   var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

   store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
   var cert = store.Certificates.Cast<X509Certificate2>().FirstOrDefault(xc => xc.Thumbprint == thumb);
   if (cert == null)
   {
       throw new Exception(string.Format("Could not find a certificate with thumbprint {0} in StoreName.{1} at StoreLocation.{2}", thumb, store.Name, store.Location));
   }
   ```

Web/Worker Roles are similar, upload the certificate to the Cloud Service via the portal (1) and skip (2).  For (3), note that certificates in Web/Worker Roles are stored in `StoreLocation.LocalMachine`.